# Running Psychopy in Pavlovia: issue with translating Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, psychopy

I created an experiment in Psychopy builder. Because of limitations in the builder I had to create a small piece of custom code. This works as it should when running the code in Psychopy builder. If I run the study online with Pavlovia everything runs fine except from the piece of custom code. Apparently this piece of code in Python should be translated to Javascript. 
I don't have any profound knowledge of either of the two languages.

This is the piece of code in Python (which works):

```
if len(avoidance.keys) != 0:
    USready = False;

if trialClock.getTime() > 19:
    UStimeCheck = True;

if (USready == True and UStimeCheck == True):
    showUS = True;

if (USready == False and UStimeCheck == True):
    continueRoutine = False;
```

This is the translation of the code above I tried in Javascript (this doesn't work):

```
if (avoidance.keys != null) {
    USready = false;
    }

if (trialClock.getTime() > 19) {
    UStimeCheck = true;
    }

if (USready == true && UStimeCheck == true) {
    showUS = true;
    }

if (USready == false && UStimeCheck == true) {
    continueRoutine = false;
    }
```

I defined the variables USready, UStimeCheck and showUS:

```
var showUS = false;
var USready = true;
var UStimeCheck = false;
```

I also tried to set USready on false and true, but this did not make any difference. 
Any ideas of what might be wrong with the code in Javascript?

Thanks!
Sara

Comment: The code *looks* OK. But I'm not sure how it doesn't work - is there an error or something? The only thing I can see is that in Python you do `len(avoidance.keys) != 0` which (I think) checks the length of the `avoidance.keys` array. In JS you have `avoidance.keys != null` which will check if `avoidance.keys` is `null` or not. I'm not sure if this is the correct thing you are after - can you clarify? I am not very good with Python.

Comment: Probably best for this to asked on the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org where the Pavlovia developers can help directly. e.g. I think there are some issues caused by using `var` in custom code on that platform, but I don't know enough of the Javascript side there myself to say anything more useful. https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/issues-with-debugging-psychojs-files/9693/6?u=michael

Comment: Thanks! I asked my question on the Psychopy forum as well.